# Get balances from all addresses in wallet.dat / json file

Tags: wallet.dat

I have a (possibly old) wallet.dat file with dozens to hundreds of addresses. It is obviously prohibitively expensive to manually look up each one.

Does anybody know a way to analyse all of them to find if any have a balance greater than 0? The current version of pywallet using `--dumpwithbalance` only lists the balance as error code: 1015 (apparently a [CloudFlare issue](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet/issues/33))

Comment: If you have a wallet.dat, you can just load it into Bitcoin Core and wait for it to sync.